# How can i save video frames into a buffer?

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

I was using **VideoCapture** to read frames from a webcam and write into a directory using **VideoWriter**. But a new idea has come to my mind like if i want to save the video on the press of a PUSH BUTTON with 50 frames back the time the button is pressed and then continue with the live frames.
Is there any way to do it.
As i have observed that writing from a source should be continous, if we are changing the source we need to reinitialize the **VideoWriter.open()**.

Answer (score 1):

So you need to store last 50 frames and write them into video file by demand.

You can use [ring buffer (circular queue)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer). Fill it with incoming frames, and every time update the oldest frame with new one. What are webcam frame format and goal OS/computer platform? In some cases memory consumption might be a problem.

When recoding starts, extract frames one-by-one and add them to VideoWriter. During this process, insert incoming frames in the buffer to avoid frame loss, until buffer is empty.

Comment: yes i need to store 50 frames and when i start recording the old 50 frames should be written using VideoWriter and then the incoming  frames, so that i can have a record of what happen before the video recording starts.

Comment: OK. I've described all that you need.